# connecting network namespaces using OVS switches and a pox controller

Tags: sdn, openvswitch, pox, virtual-network

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qopqf.png)

i connected the network namespaces to the openvswitches but i don't know how to connect the open v switches to the vNIC of my virtual machine (also what is the objective of connecting them to the NIC)  also i'm supposed to put the controller in different network namespace and connect it with the openvswitches
and  i don't know if the openvswitches will be linked trough the nic or should ai add a veth pair between them